# How to calculate an average using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the following error

[image: Error pop up]

My code below

```
GrossMean = WorksheetFunction.Average("AK21:AK100020")
        
sheet1.Cells(4, 44) = GrossMean
```

Comment: Add Range() around the reference

Answer (score 0):

Define the range and in which worksheet it is as:

```
GrossMean = WorksheetFunction.Average(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AK21:AK100020"))
```

And make sure that there is numeric data in that range. If it is empty you get the same error.